# How to animate the scaling of a cylindrical parabola only in one direction?

Tags: python, animation

I want to do an animation similar to this one but i don't know how to get the endpoints of the shape and how to move it so that the scaling animation seems static like in this gif:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPvv9.jpg

I also would be curious if there is some way to animate this kind of scaling animation for any 3d object.
Here is the code I wrote for a quick test:

````
def cylindric_parabola_animation():
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(
            type='PLAIN_AXES', 
            align='WORLD',
            location=(0, 0, 0),
            scale=(1, 1, 1))

            
    axes_object = bpy.context.active_object
    print(axes_object)
      
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
            size= 1, 
            enter_editmode=True, 
            location= (0, 0, 5), 
            rotation= (0, 0, 0), 
            scale= (5, 0.25, 2)
    )
    region, rv3d, v3d, area = view3d_find(True)
    override = {
    'scene'  : bpy.context.scene,
    'region' : region,
    'area'   : area,
    'space'  : v3d
    }

    bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(
    override, 
    MESH_OT_loopcut = {
        "object_index" : 0,
        "number_cuts"           : 40,
        "smoothness"            : 0,     
        "falloff"               : 'SMOOTH',  # Was 'INVERSE_SQUARE' that does not exist
        "edge_index"            : 11,
        "mesh_select_mode_init" : (True, True, False)
    },
    TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide = {
        "value"           : 0,
        "mirror"          : True, 
        "snap"            : False,
        "snap_target"     : 'CLOSEST',
        "snap_point"      : (0, 0, 0),
        "snap_align"      : False,
        "snap_normal"     : (0, 0, 0),
        "correct_uv"      : False,
        "release_confirm" : False
    }
    )
    
    bent_object = bpy.context.active_object
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    print(bent_object)
    
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SIMPLE_DEFORM')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["SimpleDeform"].deform_method = 'BEND'
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["SimpleDeform"].origin = axes_object
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["SimpleDeform"].deform_axis = 'Z'
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["SimpleDeform"].angle = math.radians(170)
    
    bent_object.rotation_euler[0] = math.radians(270)
    axes_object.rotation_euler[0] = math.radians(270)
          
    bent_object.scale = (1, 1, 1)
    bent_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = "scale", frame=1)
    bent_object.scale = (0.1, 1, 1)
    bent_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = "scale", frame=30)
    bent_object.scale = (1, 1, 1)
    bent_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = "scale", frame=60)
    
    axes_object.scale = (1, 1, 1)
    axes_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = "scale", frame=1)
    axes_object.scale = (0.1, 1, 1)
    axes_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = "scale", frame=30)
    axes_object.scale = (1, 1, 1)
    axes_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = "scale", frame=60)

    bent_object.location = (0, 0, 5)
    bent_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = "location", frame=1)
    bent_object.location = (-3.5, 0, 5)
    bent_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = "location", frame=30)
    bent_object.location = (0, 0, 5)
    bent_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = "location", frame=60)
    
    axes_object.location = (0, 0, 0)
    axes_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = "location", frame=1)
    axes_object.location = (-3.5, 0, 0)
    axes_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = "location", frame=30)
    axes_object.location = (0, 0, 0)
    axes_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = "location", frame=60)


 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cylindric_parabola_animation()
```
````

Comment: Suggest this could be done with hooks on two ends of a bezier curve.